# Bigdei Shabbos on Erev Pesach

Tags: shabbat, clothing, yom-tov, shulchan-aruch

It says in SA OC Siman 471 in the Rema Sif 3 that it's a mitzvah to take shower/bath and cut ones hair Erev Yom Tov. As well to wear "Bigadim Noim" (nice clothing) "c'mo Shabbos" (like on Shabbos.)

However the clothing of Yom Tov should be nicer than those of Shabbos (SA OC Siman 529). So why is the Rema saying to get ready and put on Bigadim Noim like one does on Shabbos. It could be that "c'mo b'Shabbos" means that one should get dressed nicely now just like one does for Shabbos (and not that the begadim themselves will be "c'mo", "like", those of Shabbos and rather like the ones of yom tov.

Or perhaps it could be understood like this, that the clothing (Shabbos clothing) that one should wear on davka Erev Pesach because it is more than just a normal Erev Yom Tov. Then the opposite, I would say to wear Yom Tov clothing itself.

An answer to this question could be either addressing my difficulty (which is why the Rema is seemingly telling us to get dressed with Bigdei Shabbos for Yom Tov which is in contradiction to the Shulchan Aruch in Siman 529) or perhaps correcting my understanding of the words of the Rema with a proper source or explanation (which in itself would answer the difficulty.)

Comment: Re "Or perhaps it could be understood like this, that the clothing (Shabbos clothing) that one should wear on davka Erev Pesach because it is more than just a normal Erev Yom Tov. Then the opposite, I would say to wear Yom Tov clothing itself.": maybe it's greater than another _erev yom tov_ but not greater than _Shabas_? (Just a thought. I don't know.)

Comment: @msh210 was also a consideration but I anyway am not convinced that this could be p'shat in the Rema however simply entertained the possibility.

Answer (score 2):

[Kaf HaChayyim 471:42](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.471.42.1?lang=bi) understands Rema's words like your first suggestion (i.e. "one should get dressed nicely now just like one does for Shabbos (and not that the begadim themselves will be "c'mo", "like", those of Shabbos and rather like the ones of yom tov.)")

> פי' לרחוץ ולגלח וללבוש כשבת אך הבגדים יהיו יותר נאים של יו"ט משל שבת כמ"ש לקמן סי' תקכ"ט.‏
>
> The explanation is that one washes, shaves and gets dressed like *shabbat*, but the clothes themselves should be nicer for *yom tov* than for *shabbat*, like it says later on in *siman* 529.